# How can I loop a function?

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval

I have a function 'y()' and I want to call the function on a delayed loop.

Right now I use "setInterval" so that it runs the function every 2 seconds. The setInterval is activated using the function 'z1()' through a button. But this method doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

Javascript:

```
   var x = 0-1;     
var i;
//document.getElementById("function1").innerHTML = "y()";
    function z1() {
        setInterval(
            function y() { 
                function number_string() {
                    x += 1;
                    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
                    var number = 1234567890123456789;
                    var one = String(number).charAt(x);
                    var one_as_number = Number(one); 
                    //document.write(one_as_number);
                    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = one_as_number;
                }
            },2000
        );
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="z1()">x</button>
```

Comment: All that `y()` does is define a function named `number_string()`. It never calls the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lomofo/5/edit?html,js,console,output)***

Simply remove your inner fn `function number_string() {` cause you're not calling int anywhere.
Also cache the elements you plan to reuse multiple times.

```
var x = -1; 
var disp1 = document.getElementById("display");
var disp2 = document.getElementById("display2");

function z1() {
  setInterval(function y() { 
    disp1.innerHTML = ++x;
    var number = 1234567890123456789;
    disp2.innerHTML = String(number).charAt(x);
  },2000);
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you're using `var number = 1234567890123456789;`... but probably you just like it!

Also using `Number()` and `innerHTML` makes no sense cause even if it's a String what's the difference.

Comment: I'm getting a error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", it is also increasing because of the  "setinterval".

Comment: That error suggests disp2 no longer points to an element. Even though it should not be necessary, try moving `var disp2 = document.getElementById("display2")` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You see here, that calling `y` gives back a function `number_string`. You could remove it

```
    function y() { 

            x += 1;
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
            var number = 1234567890123456789;
            var one = String(number).charAt(x);
            var one_as_number = Number(one); 
            //document.write(one_as_number);
            document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = one_as_number;

    }, 2000
```

or call it directly...

```
    function y() { 
        function number_string() {
            x += 1;
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
            var number = 1234567890123456789;
            var one = String(number).charAt(x);
            var one_as_number = Number(one); 
            //document.write(one_as_number);
            document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = one_as_number;
        } ()    // <-- see
    }, 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call `y()` from outside the `setInterval`, you need to define it outside. Otherwise, the scope of the function name is just the `z1` function.

Your code for `y()` was defining an internal function named `number_string()`, but it never called it. You should just put the code directly into the body of `y()`.

```
var x = -1;     
var i;
function y() { 
    x += 1;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
    var number = 1234567890123456789;
    var one = String(number).charAt(x);
    var one_as_number = Number(one); 
    //document.write(one_as_number);
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = one_as_number;
}

//document.getElementById("function1").innerHTML = "y()";
function z1() {
    setInterval(y,2000);
}
```